# spread out the the ticks on the axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I'm trying to make a line graph and

- the y axis should have the labels "good" at the top and "bad"at the
  bottom
- The x axis should have "1 mo, 2 mo, 3mo"

right now the problem is that the labels aren't being spread out over the length of the x axis. I made the x axis ticks look spread out by doing `var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, arr.length]).range([0, width +200])` I don't want to use the 200 part but if I don't use it the line doesn't go through the whole length of the graph. Also, for the y axis the "good" and "bad" lables are at the bottom. The "good" is supposed to be at the top and the "bad is supposed to be at the bottom.

```js
  var results = {
         "month1" : {"good" : 400,"bad" : 30} ,
         "month2" : {"good" : 800, "bad" : 100},
         "month3" : {"good" : 900, "bad" : 400}

     };

  var arr = []

  for(var key in results){
   var obj = results[key];
   arr.push(obj.good  * 2 - obj.bad * 2)
  }
  console.log(arr)

  var margin = {top : 30, right : 20, bottom : 30, left: 50},
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width-30])
  var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, arr.length]).range([0, width +200])
  var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,Math.max.apply(Math, arr)]).range([height,0])

  var tickLabels = ["1 mo", "2 mo", "3 mo"];
  var yLabel = ["bad", "good"]

  // var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(function(d, i) { return tickLabels[i]})
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(arr.length).tickFormat(function(d,i){
   return tickLabels[i]
  })

  // var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(5)
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickFormat(function(d, i) { return yLabel[i]})

  var valueline = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d, i) {return x(i)})
   .y(function(d) {return y(d)})


  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width" , width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

   // y.domain([0, d3.max(arr, function(d) {return d} )])
   // x.domain([0, 2])

   svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis)

   svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").call(xAxis).attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

  svg.append("path").attr("d", valueline(arr)).style({"fill" : "none", "stroke" : "red"}).classed("line", true)
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

I'm looking into ordinal scales now or maybe changing the structure of data to help me out. I would prefer to keep the data structure the same.

**update** I tried changing the `var y =` part to `var y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["good", "bad"]).range([height, 0])`. It gave the "good" and "bad" text at the proper place on the y axis but it messed up the line graph I think. It looks different. I Don't what the beginning of the graph to start at 0 (meaning bottom left corner)if the first element of the array is not 0.

**Update 2** I took a way the `var y` stuff I mentioned in the last update and I added `.ticks(2)` so this part looks like `var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickFormat(function(d, i) { return yLabel[i]}).ticks(2)` this causes the "good" and "bad" label to be more spread so it looks better because they're both not at the bottom. but the "good" text is not all the way at the top it look like its only three quarters of the way up the y axis. So this question is not finished. Almost there.

Still need help stretching the line graph and the labels for the `x` part.

[image: drawing of graph]

Comment: can you put a screen shot of what should the graph look like (or what you are trying to achieve).
The confusing part is that you have record like `"month3" : {"good" : 900, "bad" : 400}` so how should this 400 and 900 come on  graph since the y axis has good and bad and x axis has 1 month , 2month etc,

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I updated the question with the pic I hope you understand better. the website will have users voting all the time by clicking on "good" or "bad" button and I want to show the past three month results on the line graph. so `"month3" : {"good" : 900, "bad" : 400}` would have the y coordinate at 500 and the x cordinate at `3mo` .. `obj.good  * 2 - obj.bad * 2` might be confusing I added the `*2` because I was testing scaling. Instead of showing the intervals on the y axis. it should just show good or bad. let me know your questions.

Comment: Ok so the y is a function (obj.good * 2 - obj.bad * 2) for data `{"good" : 900, "bad" : 400}` it will be 900*2 -400*2 = 1000 but you are saying its 500. Can you correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: yes it's 500. forget that the `*2` is there, I shouldn't of put it in.

Answer (score 0):

Apart, from the y axis you have made for drawing the line, make a new scale for ordinals [good, bad]:

```
var y1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(["bad", "good"])
  .rangePoints([height, 0]);
```

Define an axis for it:

```
var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1).orient("left")
```

Draw the y axis:

```
svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis1)
```

You can have a dual y axis like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xr1gxe2zfOWQhz2pSEqv?p=preview)

Or you don't show the axis based on which the line is made like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/v3zfp2yS7F9rBhoC94oQ?p=preview)

Comment: The second  plunker looks good.. I'll have to take a look at the details tomorrow. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I just don't like how the graph isn't being spread out for the entire width. usually `.range([0, width])` would do the job, but with the way it is now I have to do `.range([0, width + 200])` and this also doesn't look like it's being spread out all the way. Why isn't the line graph being scaled the whole width? I don't like adding the fixed 200 number

Comment: OK that's a different question, please ask another SO question I think you will get a lot of answers on SO already. Please do close this if it addresses your concern :)